# How to make a reverse dictionary via `glossaries` package?

Tags: glossaries

From http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=12595

> I want to compile an new English terms on my proffesional field collections.     It's much like a dictionary but in reverse sort of words for learning convenience, e.g.

```
...
romance ...
...(other words whose root is "-ance")
science ...
...
romantic ...
...
Titantic ...
...
scientific ...
```

> I am going to write the words as follow

```
\newglossaryentry{romantic}{name=romantic,
description={(corresponding paraphrase)}
}
```

> but can't find any sort option fit my demand. Please give me a hand.

Comment: Please repost your question here again in full. Posts on TeX.SX must be mostly self-contained. Thanks.

Comment: …and with a more descriptive title.

Comment: I've pasted in the text there, but it's still not clear to me what the question is after.  This example doesn't make clear how this kind of index differs from a dictionary.

Comment: It sounds as if the words should be sorted depending on their endings (-ance, -tic). I think this could be only done if one add a sensible sort key to each entry.

Comment: As I said: Use in each entry a sort key. E.g. Fischer: sort=herfisc, Scharrer: sort=rerschar etc.

Comment: Thank what C.S. to do, and say sorry to M.S. & W.R. for my careless. I am glad to see that U.F. have understood me. There is another example: suppose we have four words **Fischer**, **Stewart**, **Robertson** and **Scharrer** (hope not offend), thus the order of them is **Roberston** (because the last letter _n_ in it is in front of the _r_ of **Scharrer** and **Fischer**, the _t_ of **Stewart** by alphabet order), and then **Fischer**, and then **Scharrer** (because the _r_er in the latter is behind the _h_er in the former), and then **Stewart**.

Comment: I understand your question. It seems you can use a quick fix with some scripting, for the `.glo` file. To convert `\glossaryentry{abc?blah blah}` to `\glossaryentry{cba?blah blah}`. It won't be very difficult to implement with awk, perl, etc.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you right you want to compile a dictionary based on some kind of two-level sorting procedure: Firstly, group the words according to a set of predefined suffixes (such as "antic" in romantic or semantic) and sort the groups; secondly, sort the words of each group.

You can do this using the tools of the [`xstring`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/xstring_doc_en.pdf) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{glossaries}
```

Define an appropriate wrapper around the `\newglossaryentry` command provided by the `glossaries` package:

```
\newcommand*{\mynewglossaryentry}[2]{%
  \bgroup%
  \StrBefore{#1}{-}[\root]%
  \StrBehind{#1}{-}[\suffix]%
  \StrExpand{{\root\suffix}{name=\root\suffix, description={#2}, sort=\suffix\root}}{\keyvallist}%
  \expandafter\newglossaryentry\keyvallist%
  \egroup%
}
```

Now, define dictionary entries as follows:

```
\mynewglossaryentry{sem-antic}{description of semantic}
\mynewglossaryentry{rom-antic}{description of romantic}
\mynewglossaryentry{immin-ence}{description of imminence}
\mynewglossaryentry{depend-ence}{description of dependence}
\mynewglossaryentry{immin-ent}{description of imminent}
\mynewglossaryentry{depend-ent}{description of dependent}

\makeglossaries
```

The hyphen in the first argument of `\mynewglossaryentry` is solely used to indicate the suffixes controlling first-level sorting. It will not show up in the dictionary. Moreover, it is not part of the label of a dictionary entry—the label is the word itself:

```
\begin{document}

\noindent
\gls{semantic}, \gls{romantic}, \gls{imminence}, \gls{dependence}, \gls{imminent}, \gls{dependent}

\printglossary[style=listgroup]

\end{document}
```

The resulting output is:

[image]